# Rest api data not getting appended to table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, html-table

I want api data to be shown in a table
 where data {title, unique_id, description} is coming from an api. I check on live.cricskill.com/fiddle.html but I am unable to append this on the table so please guide me how to do it. I checked all the ways available on Stack Overflow but none are working.

```
<table border='1' id="cricket">
    <!-- Make a Header Row -->
    <tr>
        <td><b>unique_id</b></td>
        <td><b>title</b></td>
        <td><b>description</b></td>

    </tr>
</table>

</div>
</div>


<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://cricapi.com/api/cricket/your key", true);
  xhttp.send();

</script>
```

Comment: What do you intend `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML` to do here? There is no element with the id `demo` in the code you provided. It would be helpful for you to clarify your question and explain exactly where you're having trouble.

Comment: I want api fetch details ..to show in table

Comment: This is not a clarification - you’re just restating your goal, not clarifying your problem. Please see here for more information on how to ask a good question that’s more likely to be answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I just declared the id to show on button click

Comment: You can check on www.live.cricskill.com/fiddle.html

Comment: If you want to discuss code, then you should update your question to include that code, not link to an external URL that may or may not exist in the future. Regardless, it’s very difficult to give you any guidance if you don’t provide more detailed and specific information about your question. Please edit your question to explain in detail where you’re stuck and what it is you don’t understand. Additional one-line comments will not be useful.